# How to set pseudo element CSS such as `input::placeholder` in `garden`?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

How to set  pseudo element CSS such as `input::placeholder` in `garden`?
Does `garden` supports this?

If not, how can I set `input:placeholder` CSS in a reagent project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe:

```
(css ["input::placeholder" {:font-size "16px"} ] )
```